# Can't turn off RST for ubuntu installtion?

Tags: boot, ssd, bios, ahci, rst

How do I turn off RST for the Ubuntu installation? I have 512 GB NVMe SSD and there is no option for turning off iRST or change hard disk controller to AHCI in BIOS, BIOS is at the latest version.

Comment: You can't turn it off, if there is no BIOS option.

Comment: Boot from a LiveUSB and see of your disks are detected. If the are, there is no need to disable RST.

Comment: See the instructions at https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/ubuntu-installation-on-computers-with-intel-r-rst-enabled/15347